# how to listen for a mouse click in a javascript game

Tags: javascript, html, mouseclick-event

I'm designing a game in javascript and I have a function that goes like this:

```
function handleKeys(mod) {

    if (37 in keysDown || 65 in keysDown) { //left
        player.x -= player.speed * mod; 
    }
    if (38 in keysDown || 87 in keysDown) { //up
        player.y -= player.speed * mod;
    }
    if (39 in keysDown || 68 in keysDown) { //right
        player.x += player.speed * mod;
    }
    if (40 in keysDown || 83 in keysDown) { //down
        player.y += player.speed * mod;
```

and I want to add another conditional that calls my shoot() function when I click the mouse.  How can I write that conditional so that it resembles the code above, because every tutorial I've seen just tells me how to make clickable buttons and requires me to use addEventListener, which I don't think is right for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: just do addEventListener on your canvas or whatever and set a mouseDown = true/false; Then you can handle this on your handleKeys(..) code with if(mouseDown) { // shoot

Comment: addEventListener is the best way to listen for events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mouse coordinates to tell where the shot is and use this as your html tag:

```
<html onclick="shoot()">
    <!-- code -->
</html>
```

You could also use the onclick on your canvas like:

```
<canvas onclick="shoot()" id="game_pad"></canvas>
```

Comment: but how would I put that code into javascript if I want to keep as much of the code in the separate .js file as possible?  Do you have to do it in the html or can you reference canvas in the javascript and do it there?

Comment: The only way to do it in javascript is through an eventListener or you could use jQuery. I don't know much jQuery so I can't tell you how to use the jQuery method.